# Modular Symbolic (and indexed) Matrix Creation with Sympy

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I am trying to create a symbolic and modular python function using sympy that takes in the dimensions j (rows) & k (columns) and returns a matrix indexed. Here is the function:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy import init_printing,Matrix
from sympy.physics.vector import dynamicsymbols
import numpy as np
init_printing()    
def weights_func_L(j,k):
    #
    # jth nuerons in the k ( or L - 1 ) layer   
    # j rows
    # k columns

    #in other words, this is the weight (in a specific layer j) for the jth nueron and the kth neuron in the 
    #previous (L-1 layer) i.e wjk

    #this will return a weight matrix for j rows (i.e corresponds to the # of layers) 
    #and k (corresponds to the # of nuerons)

    #
    matrix_bin = ones(j,k)
    matrix_bin = flatten(matrix_bin)
    basic_w_string  = 'w'

    for a in np.arange(len(matrix_bin)):
        #symbols(basic_w_string+str(countj)+str(countk))
        if j == k:
            matrix_bin[a] = symbols(basic_w_string+str(a // k)+str( a % j))
        else:
            matrix_bin[a] = symbols(basic_w_string+str(a // k)+str( a % j))
        #print matrix_bin[a]

#         for aa in np.arange(j):
#             matrix_bin[countj,countk] = symbols(basic_w_string+str(countj)+str(countk))
#         countj += 1
#         countk += 1


    matrix_bin2 = np.reshape(matrix_bin,(j,k))
    return Matrix(matrix_bin2)
```

This works for a square matrix:

```
weights_func_L(3,3)
```

which yields: 
[image]

However for a non square matrix such that j!=k:

`weights_func_L(5,3)` yields

[image]

similarly calling `weights_func_L(3,5)` yields:
[image]

any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `a % j` should have been `a % k`, like this:

```py
def weights_func_L(j,k):
    matrix_bin = ones(j,k)
    matrix_bin = flatten(matrix_bin)
    basic_w_string  = 'w'

    for a in np.arange(len(matrix_bin)):
        matrix_bin[a] = symbols(basic_w_string+str(a // k)+str(a % k))

    matrix_bin2 = np.reshape(matrix_bin,(j,k))
    return Matrix(matrix_bin2)
```

```py
>>> weights_func_L(5, 3)
⎡w₀₀  w₀₁  w₀₂⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎢w₁₀  w₁₁  w₁₂⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎢w₂₀  w₂₁  w₂₂⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎢w₃₀  w₃₁  w₃₂⎥
⎢             ⎥
⎣w₄₀  w₄₁  w₄₂⎦
```